# change the thread pool size of JVM

Tags: multithreading, jvm

I need to change the thread pool size of JVM . Is there any possibility to do this.
I am running a high threaded jar on JVM. Thats why the some threads goes under sleep or block stages.

Answer (score 0):

The jvm doesn't have a global thread pool per se. If you are using one of the java.util.concurrent.Executor-implementations, read up on the javadoc for that class/method. This is adjusted in java-code per pool you have created (from your code) and is not related to the JVM.

That said, please consider that each thread (typically) consumes 512k of virtual memory for it's stack, which limits the number of maximum available threds for a 32-bit jvm (but it doesn't sound like this is your problem at all).

When your threads block a lot you probably also have some kind of contention, meaning that you have some common resource that they are waiting for. Perhaps you are you using "synchronized" a lot? More threads won't solve that problem, but rather just consume more resources in the OS and JVM.

Please get back with a bit more details of what your code is doing and how, and perhaps I can help a bit more.